# Why it can not choose the value in select2 (Loading remote data)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I using select2 version 4

Demo is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/59p19q7z/52/

url aksi.php is like this :

```
[{
    "group_id": "1",
    "group_name": "Chelsea",
    "group_city": "London"
}, {
    "group_id": "2",
    "group_name": "Manchester United",
    "group_city": "Manchester"
}, {
    "group_id": "3",
    "group_name": "Manchester City",
    "group_city": "Manchester"
}]
```

My Javascript code is like this :

```
function formatRepo (repo) {
        if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

        var markup = repo.group_name;

        return markup;
     }

    function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
        return repo.group_name || repo.text;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
          ajax: {
            url: "aksi.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
              return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
              };
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {
              return {
                results: data  
              };
            },
            cache: true
          },
          escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
          minimumInputLength: 1,
          templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
          templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page  

        });
    });
```

When I select the value, It's not working. There is no hover

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Give exact path of aksi.php in ajax URL and check, In JS Fiddle it shows http://fiddle.jshell.net/59p19q7z/52/show/aksi.php?q=a not found

Comment: @Karthikeyani, I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957532/why-my-script-select2-not-working-when-i-change-select2-version